# Error from calculated results of nested IIf( ) expressions in query

Tags: ms-access, iif

I'm trying to perform a calculation based on a record's categorization into one of three groups. So, If a, then x; else if b, then y; else if c, then z. This is what I'm trying:

```
Field:IIf([Rating]<6, 
DateAdd("m",3,[Rating/Comments Date]), 
IIf(5<[Rating]<8, 
    DateAdd("m",6,[Rating/Comments Date]), 
    DateAdd("y",1,[Rating/Comments Date])))
```

Any idea why this is returning "#error" instead of the calculated DateAdd results?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `5<[Rating]<8` segment to `[Rating] BETWEEN 6 AND 7`.

Comment: Go to the design view of your table and check the format of your [Rating/Comments Date] field.  If the date is stored as a string then the DateAdd function will fail.

Comment: I have also seen this error for evaluations on null values.  Are there null values in your [Rating] or [Rating/Comments Date] fields?

Comment: Yes, there are null values in both fields. But the function still seems to work on one record in the middle of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Year is `yyyy` ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx )

How about simplifying:

```
Field:IIf([Rating]<6, 
DateAdd("m",3,[Rating/Comments Date]), 
IIf([Rating]>8, DateAdd("yyyy",1,[Rating/Comments Date]),
    DateAdd("m",6,[Rating/Comments Date])))
```

Comment: It's still returning #error for all but one record of 500. This is driving me nuts! Thank you for helping me to simplify, though.

Comment: Have you got a little sample data?

Comment: @Tony without sample data the only way I could recreate the issue you are having is when I converted the [Rating] field to numbers stored as Text.  I recommend taking another look at your table design.